# Solving $2\sqrt{ax}<3a-x$. Can I square both sides in this case?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, solution-verification

The Question is

> Given $a<0$ find range of $x$ in terms of $a$ which satisfies the inequality $2\sqrt{ax}<3a-x$

As $a<0$, therefore $x<0$

Now  $2ax$ is positive hence $3a-x$ should also be positive (As $3a-x>2\sqrt{ax}$)

As both sides are positive therefore I should be able to square both sides without getting spurious solutions
\begin{align}
& 2\sqrt{ax}<3a-x \\
\implies&4ax<9a^2+x^2-6ax\\
\implies & (x-a)(x-9a)>0\\
\implies&x\in(-\infty,9a)\cup(a,0)\\
\end{align}

But the correct answer is $x\in(-\infty,9a)$

Why am I getting spurious(extraneous) solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The assertions $2\sqrt{ax}<3a-x$ and $4ax<(3a-x)$ are equivalent when (and only when) $3a-x\geqslant0$, which happens if and only if $x\leqslant3a$, or $x\in(-\infty,3a)$. But $(a,0)\cap(-\infty,3a)=\emptyset$.